# Are you yotzei yedei chovah if you forgot to bow during shemoneh esrei?

Tags: halacha, number, shemoneh-esrei, bowing-kneeling

The sages instituted that we bow 5 times during the *shemoneh esrei* (four times throughout and once at the end).

If one forgot to bow during one of these 5 times, has he still fulfilled his obligation?

Comment: Why would bowing be meakev?

Comment: @Daniel, that is the question...

Comment: Incidentally, there are 5 required bows.

Comment: I'm asking what the motivation is behind this question. Without a motivation for asking, this question isn't any better than "Can I eat feta cheese with meat?"

Comment: @lee Is your spelling more accurate? What standard are you comparing against?

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps it's grammatically correct to say "יוצא מידי חובה" in Hebrew; but, the phrase I'm most familiar with is "יוצא ידי חובה". I attempted to transliterate "ידי" according to what I thought is Ani Yodea's shittah.

Comment: @Lee So why did you edit at all if it was correct, and why did you write "spelling" in the edit summary?

Comment: @DoubleAA I wrote "spelling", because I'm tired. I've never tried to edit an edit summary, so I'm not sure if it's possible. Also, I've never seen "מידי", so I was trying to give Ani Yodea the benefit of the doubt in my last comment. If "מידי" is indeed correct, I'll gladly revert my edit.

Comment: @maimonist Why would a transliterator change "esreh" to "esrei"?  The first is more literal, and the second doesn't add anything. I've seen it spelled the second way, but it doesn't change anything, so I can't comprehend the edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if you purposefully didn't bow, you still fulfilled your obligation (Rambam Tefillah 5:1).

Comment: but you did sin for not bowing down

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob that wasn't the question

Comment: @Daniel no bout from what this answer is saying, one can come to think that even if i did not bow on purpose i have fulfilled the obligation of prayer, so therefore i wont bow at all and just fulfill my obligation this way. that is why it should be noted that the obligation is fulfilled but you still sinned for purposefully not bowing

Comment: @mori I don't think anyone will make that mistake

Comment: @DoubleAA people frequent this site who might be looking for halocho and are not educated enough or something along those lines...